# High tup_returned value for a dormant database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I was reviewing some statistics on a set of production databases on a Postgresql-9.3 server by running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_database ORDER BY tup_returned DESC;
```

I noticed some interesting numbers for a particular database. I know that the database is dormant and should have zero activity, yet it was reporting a `tup_returned` count of 698378 for the last ~24 hours. Per the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-DATABASE-VIEW), `tup_returned` is the:

> Number of rows returned by queries in this database.

There is no possible way that our queries could account for this row count.

I then connected to the database and ran this command to try to figure out which tables were responsible for the usage:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_all_tables;
```

All of the activity for `seq_tup_read`, `idx_scan`, and `idx_tup_fetch` was logged for `pg_*` tables such as `pg_database`, `pg_authid`, `pg_tablespace`, etc. None of the tables we created had any kind of count higher than ~3-4.

Anyone know why or how all of this activity is being recorded if the table is dormant?

Comment: The number reported in pg_stat_database is since the last startup, not in the last 24 hours. I _think_ queries done by internal processes also increase `tup_returned`, e.g. autovacuum and the statistics collector.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the reply -- your help is much appreciated. In this case the server had been rebooted roughly 24 hours prior. The value reported in the `stats_reset` column was early AM 8/28/2017. Any idea why autovacuum would churn on a largely dormant database albeit populated with a significant amount of data (i.e., dozen tables, tens of thousands of rows)?